# Listing all the subclasses of a specific class in Java

Tags: java, subclass

How do I list down all the subclasses of a specific class or all the implementers of a specific interface in Java? Using Eclipse, I am able to do so but I want to know how to perform this programmatically? If you have any suggestions, please do put them.

Comment: you can do so using java reflection

Comment: @N.berouain. For some very narrow definition of "all", perhaps

Answer (score 4):

take a look at [reflection](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), Basic usage of this:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.package");    
Set<Class<? extends InterfaceExample>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(InterfaceExample.class);
```

Comment: ok, but with reflection can you scan an entire package or classpath also?

Comment: yes it's possible, like this:

 `Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.package");`

 `Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = 
     reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);`

Comment: But reflection works fine with latest versions of Java?

Answer (score 0):

As per me, this requires the following steps in the least:

1. For the current classloader, iterate over the classpath to get the list of folders and JARs (This, I know how to only for `URLClassLoader` and its subtypes, which is `URLClassLoader.getURLs()`)
2. Visit/read each folder or JAR in the list from (1) to know the classes in it and load each class (there could be an issue here with the classloader, but you may get it through for most cases)
3. Reflect and find out the implemented interfaces (if you are looking for children of interfaces) or superclass (if a class). This has to be done iteratively till you reach `java.lang.Object` or the target interface or class.

Repeat the above steps for the parent classloader if the parent interface or class was loaded by them (say, `java.util.List`).

All said and done, please be ready for a memory and CPU heavy processing. :)

Eclipse, I think indexes the hierarchy progressively. That is why, most of the times it shows the results fast. I am not sure of it, but it may be worth exploring Eclipse if it provides a way to access its type hierarchy list at runtime (through plugin implementations).